# How to extract 'month' from date given in character form?

Tags: r, date

I have to extract month from the date format that looks like this: 01-Dec-2016 etc. It is not in the standard date format and R does not read it like a date

I have tried entering coding on R that will read it as date but it gives me an error term

```
event_date<- as.Date(ACLED_combined$event_date)
```

> Error in charToDate(x) : 
>     character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

As final exercise, I have to divide the data into quarters and that depends on the year and month for the event. For that I first need to convert the date into month. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: `as.Date("01-Dec-2016", "%d-%b-%Y")`  to convert to `Date` class.  See `?strptime` for the percent codes.

Comment: Thanks. That has worked for converting it to a date form. But how do I extract the month from this date now? All the codes I find on this website are for the format where the date is numeric form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the string as a datatime object by calling the function as.POSXct(). Then you can use the format() function to just show the month from 1 to 12. Below is an example:

```
> datestring <- c('01-Dec-2016', '01-Jan-2017','01-Feb-2017')
> datetime <- as.POSIXct(datestring, format = '%d-%b-%Y')
> datetime
[1] "2016-12-01 CST" "2017-01-01 CST" "2017-02-01 CST"
> as.numeric(format(datetime, '%m'))
[1] 12  1  2
```

Comment: I agree with everything else, but why `POSIXct` when these are just plain old dates? `as.Date(datestring, format = '%d-%b-%Y')` for instance.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. The function as.Date() also works. My preference is to use POSIXct in case there are also time elements in the string. Feel free to choose any solution that works or makes more sense for you.

Answer (score 1):

try using `lubridate`package.

```
library(lubridate)

# creates a date object
dmy("01-Dec-2016")

# using date object, you can find the month - you have several options
lubridate::month(dmy("01-Dec-2016"))
lubridate::month(dmy("01-Dec-2016"), label = TRUE)
lubridate::month(dmy("01-Dec-2016"), label = TRUE, abbr = FALSE)
```